# Docker DNS not working. 'sleep 1' helps. Timing issue?

Tags: docker, nextcloud

I'm trying to install nextcloud-aio-mastercontainer but I'm having strange problem where the container can not connect to internet. I've created a bridge network 'dockernet'.

If I use busybox and ping nextcloud.com it works but when running the container - with the same network - it can't resolve nextcloud.com. Okay it seems like a dns issue but I don't know how to continue from this.

```
root@truenas[~]# docker run --network=dockernet busybox sleep 1;ping nextcloud.com
PING nextcloud.com (95.217.53.155) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from nextcloud.com (95.217.53.155): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=10.7 ms
64 bytes from nextcloud.com (95.217.53.155): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=9.70 ms
64 bytes from nextcloud.com (95.217.53.155): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=10.1 ms
64 bytes from nextcloud.com (95.217.53.155): icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=9.54 ms
^C
--- nextcloud.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 9.540/10.020/10.717/0.454 ms
root@truenas[~]# sudo docker run \                                                                      
--init \
--sig-proxy=false \
--name nextcloud-aio-mastercontainer \
--publish 80:80 \
--publish 8080:8080 \
--publish 8443:8443 \
--volume nextcloud_aio_mastercontainer:/mnt/docker-aio-config \
--volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro --dns=1.1.1.1 --network=dockernet \
nextcloud/all-in-one:latest
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/nextcloud-aio-mastercontainer" is already in use by container "96859859b86015be1a0f3482d06a1488d67d54b7d32fa51db01d2f0fe1c0d42e". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
See 'docker run --help'.
root@truenas[~]# docker rm 96859859b86015be1a0f3482d06a1488d67d54b7d32fa51db01d2f0fe1c0d42e
96859859b86015be1a0f3482d06a1488d67d54b7d32fa51db01d2f0fe1c0d42e
root@truenas[~]# sudo docker run \                                                         
--init \
--sig-proxy=false \
--name nextcloud-aio-mastercontainer \
--publish 80:80 \
--publish 8080:8080 \
--publish 8443:8443 \
--volume nextcloud_aio_mastercontainer:/mnt/docker-aio-config \
--volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro --dns=1.1.1.1 --network=dockernet \
nextcloud/all-in-one:latest
Trying to fix docker.sock permissions internally...
Adding internal www-data to group ping
Could not resolve the host nextcloud.com.
Most likely the DNS resolving does not work.
You should be able to fix this by following https://dockerlabs.collabnix.com/intermediate/networking/Configuring_DNS.html
Apart from that, there has been this: https://github.com/nextcloud/all-in-one/discussions/2065
root@truenas[~]# 
root@truenas[~]#
```